# Restoration State in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

[Resolved] I try to use the restoration state protocol in order to retrieve what has been programmatically build in my code, my syntax is good but it seems that it does not work.
In my code I developed a UIButton, when I click on it it creates a UIImageView, but when I kill the app and come back, the UIImageView created is not here anymore.
Here is the code :

```
class ScrollViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {
var x1 = 200
var testpost = UIImageView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let addButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 20, width: 100, height: 40))
    addButton.backgroundColor = .black
    addButton.setTitle("add a note", for: .normal)
    addButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(addButton)
    }

func buttonAction(sender: UIButton!) {
    x1 = x1 + 30
    testpost = UIImageView(frame:CGRect(x: x1,y: 0,width: 240,height: 240))
    testpost.image = UIImage(named:"Screenshots 2017-04-18 at 19.41.04")
    view.addSubview(testpost)
    testpost.restorationIdentifier = "testpostId"

}

override func encodeRestorableState(with coder: NSCoder) {
    if let imagge = testpost.image {
        coder.encode(UIImagePNGRepresentation(imagge), forKey: "testpostId")
    }
    super.encodeRestorableState(with: coder)

}
override func decodeRestorableState(with coder: NSCoder) {
    if let imagge2 = coder.decodeObject(forKey: "testpostId") as? Data {
        testpost.image = UIImage(data: imagge2)
        super.decodeRestorableState(with: coder)
    }}}
```

However i tried with a scroll view and it works well, when I launched the app after killing it, it was at the same position before quitting.

I also added this in AppDelegate :

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, shouldSaveApplicationState coder: NSCoder) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, shouldRestoreApplicationState coder: NSCoder) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

I gave a Restoration Id to my view controller also, directly from storyboard.
I haven't got any error, but nothing is saved. Any idea where is my mistake ?
thank you in advance !

Solution, Add :

```
testpost.frame = CGRect(x: x1,y: 0,width: 240,height: 240)
view.addSubview(testpost)
```

after

```
super.decodeRestorableState(with: coder)
```

And it works :) Thank for your help

Comment: Is your function decodeRestorableState ever called?  Does it retrieve the data for the image and does that data look reasonable?

Comment: Have you added a breakpoint to make sure `encodeRestorableState` and `decodeRestorableState` are called?  If so, even though you are assigning an image to `testpost`, you're never actually adding it to the screen during restoration.

Comment: @ScottThompson How could I know if it's actually called ? 
I thought that adding the 2 functions shouldSave and shouldRestore would be enough, is it ?

Also, it seems that my app saves the data because : when I launch my app again, it gets back exactly to how it was before quitting BUT only for a second, then it disapear and come back to how it is when I launch the app for the first time (tell me if its not clear)

Comment: @BrianNickel I'm not sure to understand (I'm new to coding sorry). Do you mean adding a breakpoint before both functions encode/decodeRestorableState ? For me, if I do it, both line won't be run, am I wrong ?

Comment: My suggestion would be to set a breakpoint in the function and see if it's called when you run the application.  Alternatively you could print something inside the function and see if it shows up in the terminal.

Comment: @ScottThompson I tried with a print, it seems encode is run when I go in background, and decode is run when I launch the app again, as expected. Memory of what has been built previously still appears for one second, and disappears. Any other idea ? :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments, it looks like you are successfully loading the image into `testpost`, so restoration is working.  The problem though, is that you never run any code to add `testpost` to `view` or set the frame of `testpost`.  The image stored in the image view is just one part of the state that you need to restore.

If you add the following to `decodeRestorableState` you should see what you're expecting, at least for a single image:

```
x1 = x1 + 30
testpost.frame = CGRect(x: x1,y: 0,width: 240,height: 240)
view.addSubview(testpost)
```

Your code currently doesn't handle cases where the button's been pressed multiple times (always just showing zero or one images) but you should be able to work that out from here.

Comment: It works ! thank you very much ! 
That's going to help me a lot ! :)